# Shorter Uri in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, routes, uri

I have it ->

```
$route['posts/index'] = 'posts/index';
$route['posts/create'] = 'posts/create';
$route['posts/update'] = 'posts/update';
$route['posts/(:any)'] = 'posts/view/$1';
$route['posts'] = 'posts/index';
```

has it got way to short $route['posts/index'],$route['posts/create'],$route['posts/update'] etc to one code ? idk like `$route['posts/(:any)'] = 'posts/$2';` ?

Comment: Not sure what you're after. All these should just work without a $route entry. Like `www.yourdomain.com/posts/create` would automatically call `create` method in `posts` controller. If you want `www.yourdomain.com/create` to go to `posts/create`, put in `$route['create'] = 'posts/create';`

Comment: CodeIgniter is not like some frameworks that need you to specify a route that maps to a controller/method.